# TextMate equivalent to gVim Ctrl+P

Tags: java, javascript, vim, textmate, keymapping

To auto complete a previously written string.

Is it possible?

**EDIT**
I'm editing javascript/java if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the autocomplete key is 'escape' by default. See the [TextMate manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text#working_with_text) for further information.

Comment: Thank you!!! it was driving me crazy!!! :)  About the manual... mhhhh ... mmhh well.. Beside having to write my own product user manual ( which I hate and usually I avoid ) do I have to read others  them too??? :) :) :)  ;) Thanks again

Comment: Also, Google "Textmate tips" - I seem to pick up something new in every blogpost I read about TM.